# Парсер не выдает искомую страницу

Tags: python, парсер

Итак, пытаюсь получить страницу госзакупок:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import bs4

def get_page(keyword, page_number):
    link = f'http://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/extendedsearch/results.html?searchString={keyword}&morphology=on&openMode=USE_DEFAULT_PARAMS&pageNumber={page_number}&sortDirection=false&recordsPerPage=_10&showLotsInfoHidden=false&fz44=on&fz223=on&fz94=on&pc=on&currencyIdGeneral=-1&publishDateFrom=01.01.2017&publishDateTo=31.12.2018&updateDateTo=29.05.2019&region_regions_5277343=region_regions_5277343&regions=5277343&regionDeleted=false&sortBy=UPDATE_DATE&exclText=проект+коммунальный+ТКО+ТБО+бытовой+норматив+разработка+поставка+реконструкция+сточный+дезинфекция+обучение+персонал+радиоактивный+ремонт'
    return link

page = requests.get(get_page('отход', 1))
page.encoding = 'utf8'
page = page.text
soup = BS(page, 'html.parser')
```

В ответ получаю :

```py
in: soup.title
out: <title> Страница не найдена </title>
```

При этом в браузере эта страница открывается без проблем, хотя и с пятнадцатисекундной (примерно) задержкой.

Вопрос: В чём может быть причина и как это можно вылечить?

P.S. 
Этот метод:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update = ({
"""
    здесь был useragent
"""
})
```

не принёс результата

Comment: Приветствую!)) Конкретно с вашим примером не помогу, но видел на github-е [вот такой парсер](https://github.com/chistovod/zakupki-parser/blob/master/parse.py)

Comment: requests не понимает кириллицу в url, ищите способы перекодировки (urllib в помощь)

Answer (score 0):

Всё решилось очень просто. 
Если знать.

Оказывается, нужно обходить защиту сайта, эмулируя реального пользователя.
Я это сделал при помощи библиотеки fake_useragent:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
page = requests.get(link, headers={'User-Agent': UserAgent().chrome})
```